# Call a function when the content inside a div is changed?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I have a page, on the left there is a list of links users can click, when they are clicked, a div on the right side will load the correct content via Ajax according to the link.
Now I want to fire a function when the right side div's content changed every time.
After a search in Stack Overflow, I learn that there are [Mutation Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-mutationevents), I use the `DOMSubtreeModified` event:

```
right_div.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", handler, false);
```

However, when I click the link on the left side, it seems that `handler` will be called several time.  I want it be called only once when the new contents of it has been loaded. How could I do this?

Comment: These events are not widely supported in all browsers yet, how about you add a a call back function to the function modifying the content?

Comment: @lbu actually, that's not my site, I want to write a user script to add some useful functionality to it, and  it just need to run in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: Really hard to help without seeing your code. But if the handler is being called several times, that probably means the DOM subtree is being modified several times :-)... so maybe that's not what you want to use. Can't use just use a callback, e.g., wait for readyState to be complete, then fire your function (I assume jQuery isn't an option since you didn't add that tag)?

Comment: @squidbe yes, I don't want to include JQuery, but how could I access readyState in user script?

Comment: @squidbe - the way I read the MDC documentation, [readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.readyState) events dispatched during document loading, not manipulation.

Comment: @RobG, wong2 said he's using ajax and wants his handler to be called once when the response has loaded, so readyState is appropriate, yes? E.g., if(ajaxRequest.readyState === 4) { // Call handler }

It's certainly possible, though, that I'm misunderstanding the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

The *[DOMSubtreeModified](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMSubtreeModified)* is "*a general event for notification of all changes to the document*". You can set mutation events for specific mutations:

1. [DOMAttrModified](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMAttrModified) event
2. [DOMCharacterDataModified](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMCharacterDataModified) event
3. [DOMNodeInserted](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMNodeInserted) event
4. [DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument) event
5. [DOMNodeRemoved](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMNodeRemoved) event
6. [DOMNodeRemovedFromDocument](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMNodeRemovedFromDocument) event

And there are the following types:

1. [DOMElementNameChanged](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMElementNameChanged)
2. [DOMAttributeNameChanged](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMAttributeNameChanged)

So if you are replacing a node, it might cause two (or more) mutation events - one when the node is removed, another when it is replaced. Futher events may also be dispatched, such as character data modified. if you are listening for an event only when the text content is changed, try the [DOMCharacterDataModified](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMCharacterDataModified) event:

> A user agent must dispatch this event
>   after `CharacterData.data` or
>   `ProcessingInstruction.data` have been
>   modified, but the node itself has not
>   been inserted or deleted. The proximal
>   event target of this event must be the
>   `CharacterData` node or the
>   `ProcessingInstruction` node.

Comment: Oh, I know why it will be called several times now. But I can't use `DOMCharacterDataModified` because it's not only text content in the right div, there are other divs in it.

Comment: Then I suppose you'll have to filter the events to work out which to respond to and which to ignore.