# Javascript: how to check if data is loaded

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome plugin. It injects a class name to every  tag.

I have some problems with webpages such as facebook in which content is loaded afterwards when you scroll down.

I'd like to know if there a way to check if new content is loaded.

By now the only solution I could find is a

```
 setInterval(function() {
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `DOMSubtreeModified` event ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events)) that Chrome supports - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210159/call-a-function-when-the-content-inside-a-div-is-changed) for details. Your code should look something like this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
  $("*:not(.my_class)").addClass('my_class');
}, true);
```

Comment: Thanks @kdzwinel, it actually works. I'm using the "DOMNodeInserted". The only thing is that I have the impression it slows down the loading a lot, but I'm not sure. Do you think is possible?

Comment: Make sure to fire your script at the end of the document (or, if possible, even with some timeout delay after document is fully loaded), it is probable that `DOMSubtreeModified` is fired multiple times when DOM is first created and when Facebook loads and creates the page using multiple AJAX calls. Generally speaking, your extension will be quite heavy on javascript heavy websites and web apps.

Answer (score 1):

As `Konrad Dzwinel` said, you can use some [`Mutation Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference) listener

```
document.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", methodToRun);
```

But note that the [`Mutation Events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Mutation_events) are performance hogs which can't really be tamed well (they fire too often and slow down the page a lot). Therefore, they have been deprecated over a year ago and should be used only when really needed. However, they work.

If you want this for a Chrome extension, you could use the new and shiny [`Mutation Observers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_Mutation_Observers) from DOM Level 4 (follow the links there, they explain a lot!). Where `DOMSubtreeModified` fired a thousand times, `MutationObserver` fires only once with all the modifications contained and accessible.

Works for (as of 2012/06):

- Chrome 18+ (prefixed, `window.WebKitMutationObserver`)
- Firefox 14+ (unprefixed)
- WebKit nightlies